# How to extract a time stamp from a string variable in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have the following data in a column b which is part of table x.

```
    Table x   Column b
              {"op":"&","c":[{"type":"date","d":">=","t":1459756800}],"showc":[true]}        
              {"op":"&","showc":[true],"c":[{"type":"date","d":">=","t":1460534400}]}
```

I tried to use the query table below to extract my data but does not work, as the timestamps are in different positions.

```
          SELECT substring(Column b, 44 , 10)  
          FROM Table x
```

How would I go about extracting just the timestamp.
Much Appreciated

Answer (score 1):

This answer is for MySQL < 5.7, seems 5.7 added json support

Native querying does not support JSON parsing which would lead to all kinds of trouble if you tried to parse this column as a string. Example of issue would a difference in timestamp's value placement due to different proprieties, string length, etc.

You need to add json parsing support either through script (php, ...) or augment mysql functionality

I never got around to use it but common-schema could help you out. I am sure there are other ways
https://code.google.com/archive/p/common-schema/

Usage example from http://mechanics.flite.com/blog/2013/04/08/json-parsing-in-mysql-using-common-schema/:

```
mysql> select common_schema.extract_json_value(f.event_data,'/age') as age,
    ->   common_schema.extract_json_value(f.event_data,'/gender') as gender,
    ->   sum(f.event_count) as event_count 
    -> from json_event_fact f
    -> group by age, gender;
```

Comment: Thanks @user3802077 it has worked in mysql, its unfortunate that the reporting tool I am using does not support json parsing function